# Error Message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm writing a program for my GCSE coursework that works like a vending machine. I'm trying to minus a variable off of a re-written variable and for some reason it is just not working. Help?

```
This is my code:
credit=raw_input("Please input your change, CAREFUL! This Machine only accepts 10p,20p,50p and £1: ")
list1= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
price1=0.65
price2=0.70
price3=0.50
price4=0.70
price5=0.80
while (credit) == 0:
   (credit)=raw_input("Please input your change: ")
products = (" 1) Kinder Bueno\n 2) Doritos Chilli Heatwave\n 3) Nestle Yorkie Bar\n 4) Coca Cola(Can)\n 5) Volvic Stawberry Water")
print (credit)
print ("The product selection is the following")
print (products)
(selection)=raw_input("Please select a product: ")
if (selection) == (list1[0]):
   (new_credit)=int(credit-price1)
   print (new_credit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python all of your `(` `)` are redundant and i believe what you really meant was.

```
credit = raw_input("Please input your change, CAREFUL! This Machine only accepts 10p,20p,50p and £1: ")
list1= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
price1 = 0.65
price2 = 0.70
price3 = 0.50
price4 = 0.70
price5 = 0.80
while credit == 0:
   credit = raw_input("Please input your change: ")
products = " 1) Kinder Bueno\n 2) Doritos Chilli Heatwave\n 3) Nestle Yorkie Bar\n 4) Coca Cola(Can)\n 5) Volvic Stawberry Water"
print credit
print "The product selection is the following"
print products
selection = raw_input("Please select a product: ")
if selection == list1[0]:
   new_credit = int(credit) - price1  # NOTE THE CHANGE HERE :)
   print new_credit
```

Note the change above (besides removing the redundant parens).  The cast should be around just the credit and not the credit sans the price.

### Note

For compatibility with Python3 it may be worthwhile to put the parens in with your print statements (as print is now a function) but they're absolutely not needed for control flow statements such as if / else / while...etc

Comment: Thanks ever so much :) New to this sort of stuff, but that's a big help thankyou.

Comment: @BradleyOnyett Awesome, if this helps don't forget to upvote / mark as an answer :) so that others may find it!

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me again with the code, as I have encountered another problem?

Comment: @BradleyOnyett If you would like you can post another question and link it here or similar.  This way other people with similar issues can help.

Comment: The problem is, I am restricted 1 question per 90 minutes, so I need help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514728/decimal-subtraction