# Decimal Subtraction

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

Help, Im writing a vending machine based program, and the user's credit is re-displayed to the user when they purchase an item, but all prices are in decimal form. But when I purchase an item, it subtracts the item price from 1, instead of subtracting it from 1.20 for example. Any ideas?

My code is:

```
credit = raw_input("Please input your change, CAREFUL! This Machine only accepts 10p,20p,50p and £1: \n Please enter your change in Pence (Decimal form). e.g' 1.35  ")
list1= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
price1 = 0.65
price2 = 0.70
price3 = 0.50
price4 = 0.70
price5 = 0.80
while credit == 0:
   credit = float(raw_input("Please input your change: ")))
products = " 1) Kinder Bueno\n 2) Doritos Chilli Heatwave\n 3) Nestle Yorkie Bar\n 4) Coca Cola(Can)\n 5) Volvic Stawberry Water"
print credit
print "The product selection is the following"
print products
selection = raw_input("Please select a product: ")
if selection == list1[0]:
   new_credit = int(float(credit)) - price1 
   print "Your remaining credit is:",new_credit
elif selection == list1[1]:
   new_credit = int(float(credit)) - price2
   print "Your remaining credit is: ",new_credit
elif selection == list1[2]:
   new_credit = int(float(credit)) - price3
   print "Your remaining credit is: ",new_credit
elif selection == list1[3]:
   new_credit = int(float(credit)) - price4
   print "Your remaining credit is: ",new_credit
elif selection == list1[0]:
   new_credit = int(float(credit)) - price5
   print "Your remaining credit is: ",new_credit
```

It still truncates and returns the following:

```
Please input your change, CAREFUL! This Machine only accepts 10p,20p,50p and £1: 
 Please enter your change in Pence (Decimal form). e.g' 1.35  1.35
1.35
The product selection is the following
 1) Kinder Bueno
 2) Doritos Chilli Heatwave
 3) Nestle Yorkie Bar
 4) Coca Cola(Can)
 5) Volvic Stawberry Water
Please select a product: 1
Your remaining credit is: 0.35
```

Comment: You do `int(float(number))` which rounds it to an int.

Comment: @Ngenator So what should I do instead, to stop it rounding?

Comment: @Ngenator Because when I use float alone, the program does not function correctly

Comment: How does it not function correctly.  I see you casting to int a lot and that will always truncate the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code bugged me alot. I made some changes to make things more pythonic...

1. Instead of separate lists for your menu, I made it a list of tuples containing the product and it's price
2. I fixed your float casts

There's alot to be done for example, catching errors on invalid inputs, checking for available credit before subtracting price, etc...

```
products = [
    ("Kinder Bueno", 0.65),
    ("Doritos Chilli Heatwave", 0.70),
    ("Nestle Yorkie Bar", 0.50),
    ("Coca Cola(Can)", 0.70),
    ("Volvic Stawberry Water", 0.80)
]  
min_price = min(products, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
credit = float(raw_input("Please input your change, CAREFUL! This Machine only accepts 10p,20p,50p and £1: \n Please enter your change in Pence, at least {0} (Decimal form). e.g' 1.35  ".format(min_price)))

while credit < min_price:
    credit += float(raw_input("Please input more change, you have {0} available, please input at least {1} more: ".format(credit, min_price - credit)))

print "You have {0} credit available.".format(credit)
print "The product selection is the following:"
for i, (product, price) in enumerate(products):
    print "  {0}) {1} {2}".format(i, product, price)

selection = int(raw_input("Please select a product: "))

if 0 >= selection < len(products):
    product, price = products[selection]
    print "You bought {0} for {1}".format(product, price)
    new_credit = credit - price
    print "Your remaining credit is: ", new_credit
```

With the list of tuples, you can easily get a minimum price to ensure the user has enough to actually buy something:

```
min_price = min(products, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
```

which gets the tuple with the lowest price and stores just the price in `min_price`

Comment: this is all well and good, and I'm very appreciative of this, but there is one slight problem... I have to explain my code step-by-step in the written work and a lot of these strings you have used I have no idea of, for example, what is "key=lambda x:x[1])[1]" so should I stick to my original or go with this?

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, go with yours, but feel free to use my version to learn. Lambdas are inline functions, and the [1] just accesses the second element of the tuple.

Comment: See my current code works, but like you said, it is very unpythonic, however we have not moved onto things such as tuples withing GCSE Computer Science? So I could use Tuples, as I half understand them, however I do not understand hwo to call them up?

Comment: Just like a `list` except it's immutable, a `tuple` is very basically a `list` that can't be changed. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple

Comment: I will stick to my code, as we can get no marks if there are signs of plaguerism, however I will use this code to increase my understanding on tuples, thanks a lot :)